# Spring integration 4.3.12 - Is there a LastModifiedFileListFilter for SFTP?

Tags: spring, spring-integration, spring-integration-sftp

I have searched the documents and cannot see a LastModifiedFileListFilter for SFTP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's indeed no such an implementation for SFTP.

It's not so hard so to copy/paste existing `LastModifiedFileListFilter` and apply logic for the `LsEntry` and its `getAttrs().getMTime()`.

With our `SftpStreamingMessageSource` I even start thinking that we need to provide out-of-the-box implementation for such a `lastmodified` logic.

Feel free to raise a JIRA on the matter.

Comment: Thank Artem, I've created my own filter based on LastModifiedFileListFilter and getAttrs().getMTime(). It's working a treat.

Answer (score 1):

This might help someone so here is my filter:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.integration.file.filters.FileListFilter;
import com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.LsEntry;

public class LastModifiedLsEntryFileListFilter implements FileListFilter<LsEntry> {

    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LastModifiedLsEntryFileListFilter.class);
    private static final long DEFAULT_AGE = 60;

    private volatile long age = DEFAULT_AGE;

    public long getAge() {
        return this.age;
    }

    public void setAge(long age) {
        setAge(age, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }

    public void setAge(long age, TimeUnit unit) {
        this.age = unit.toSeconds(age);
    }

    @Override
    public List<LsEntry> filterFiles(LsEntry[] files) {

        List<LsEntry> list = new ArrayList<LsEntry>();

        long now = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000;

        for (LsEntry file : files) {

            if (file.getAttrs()
                    .isDir()) {
                continue;
            }

            int lastModifiedTime = file.getAttrs()
                .getMTime();

            if (lastModifiedTime + this.age <= now) {
                list.add(file);
            } else {
                log.info("File [{}] is still being uploaded...", file.getFilename());
            }
        }
        return list;
    }

}
```